# Using self.image and current_frame to animate the sprite of an enemy in pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am trying to animate a TRUMP enemy for a video game in pygame. I have all my images loaded and I would like to have him move around at random. I am having a hard time getting the enemy TRUMP character's image to animate. I can get his initial frame to display but after that I am lost. You will see the troubled area in the code in the animate2 function.
I am confused about how I will use current_frame2 or self.image to update his sprite. Does anyone know how to proceed?

```
class TRUMP(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.game = game
        self.current_frame2 = 0
        self.last_update2 = 0
        self.load_images()
        self.animate2()

        self.image = self.TRUMP_fingers_l[0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (WIDTH *3/4), (589)
        self.pos = vec((WIDTH/2), (HEIGHT/2))
        self.vel = vec(0, 0)
        self.acc = vec(0, 0)

        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()

    def load_images(self):

        self.TRUMP_fingers_l = [self.game.spritesheet.get_image(503, 1, 248, 559)]
        for frame in self.TRUMP_fingers_l:
            frame.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.TRUMP_walk1_l = [self.game.spritesheet.get_image(643, 562, 249, 448)]
        self.TRUMP_walk2_l = [self.game.spritesheet.get_image(894, 474, 249, 448)]
        self.TRUMP_hailing = [self.game.spritesheet.get_image(1, 571, 248, 439)]
        self.TRUMP_throwing = [self.game.spritesheet.get_image(753, 1, 248, 471)]
        self.TRUMP_smug = [self.game.spritesheet.get_image(252, 1, 249, 562)]
        self.TRUMP_flexing_l = [self.game.spritesheet.get_image(1, 1, 249, 568)]

    def animate2(self):

       now = pg.time.get_ticks()
       if now - self.last_update2 > 200:
            self.last_update2 = now
            self.current_frame2 = self.TRUMP_hailing[0]
            self.image = self.TRUMP_hailing[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you only need a `index` variable (if the timer works correctly) that you  increment to cycle through the image lists. Use modulo `% len(self.TRUMP_hailing)` to keep the index in the correct range.

```
    # In the __init__ method:
    self.index = 0

def animate2(self):
    now = pg.time.get_ticks()
    if now - self.last_update2 > 200:
        self.index += 1
        self.index %= len(self.TRUMP_hailing)
        self.last_update2 = now
        self.current_frame2 = self.TRUMP_hailing[self.index]
        self.image = self.TRUMP_hailing[self.index]
```